# Issue's with running my trainer.py file using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, path, face-recognition, haar-classifier

After getting my facial capture component to work (I can gather photos that will be used for the dataset) I am trying to run a trainer.py file that will train the module but I am having some issues with my code. I am new to all of this so someone who is experienced with OpenCV, face rec and python might be able to help me a bit more.

Here is my code.
https://pastebin.com/uSX0Z8qa

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
 
# Path for face image database
path = "dataset"
 
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
 
# function to get the images and label data
def getImagesAndLabels(path):
 
    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]     
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []
 
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
 
        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # convert it to grayscale
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')
 
        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)
 
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            ids.append(id)
 
    return faceSamples,ids
 
print ("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ...")
faces, ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))
 
# Save the model into trainer/trainer.yml
recognizer.write('trainer/trainer.yml') # recognizer.save() worked on Mac, but not on Pi
 
# Prints the number of faces trained and end program
print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

And here is the error I am getting after running it

`[INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ... Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Code\OpenCV\trainer\trainer.py", line 34, in <module>     faces, ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)   File "c:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Code\OpenCV\trainer\trainer.py", line 25, in getImagesAndLabels     faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy) tion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please put your code here, not on an external bin (where it will expire, and render your question useless)  -- and the error says, your cascade file was not found / loaded

Comment: @berak Yeah I figured it wasn't loading it but do you know a way to fix it?

Comment: fix the path to it ?

Comment: various existing answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=!empty()+in+function+%27cv%3A%3ACascadeClassifier%3A%3AdetectMultiScale%27 please take the [tour] and review [ask]